# get un common strings from 2 array of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 lists like this

```
first = ['A' , 'B' , 'c' , 'd']
second = ['a' , 'b', 'e']
```

I want in result `['c' , 'd' ,'e']` . as It's case insensitive and want uncommon from both lists

tried so far :

```
   a, b = list(set(a) - set(b)),
    list(set(b) - set(a))
 
    print("list1 : ", a)
    print("list2 : ", b)
```

but not working for case in sensitive

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: What would "uncommon" mean, in this context?

Comment: @Haroldo_OK which are not present in both . If present even if  like 'a' and 'A' it should count as same. like case in senstive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a difference between the union and the intersection -

```py
(set(map(str.lower, first)) | set(map(str.lower, second))) - (set(map(str.lower, first)) & set(map(str.lower, second)))
```

**Output**

```
{'c', 'd', 'e'}
```

Comment: it is returning me strings . I need in array form

Comment: btw, you just want the symmetric difference, `^` or `.symmetric_difference`

Comment: @newbiee it's returning a *set*. If you want a *list* then just make a list out of it

Answer (score 1):

With these compression lists we can find the uncommon characters while maintaining the incase sensitive strategy. In addition, the output of the function will keep the font (lower, upper) of the original lists:

```py
first = ["A", "B", "c", "d"]
second = ["a", "b", "e"]


def in_case_sensitive(first, second):
    first_unmatched = [f for f in first if f.lower() not in [s.lower() for s in second]]
    second_unmatched = [
        s for s in second if s.lower() not in [f.lower() for f in first]
    ]

    return first_unmatched + second_unmatched


print(in_case_sensitive(first, second))
```

```bash
>>> ['c', 'd', 'e']
```

with this other lists:

```py
first = ["A", "B", "C", "d"]
second = ["a", "b", "E"]
```

the output (preserving letter type) is:

```bash
>>> ['C', 'd', 'E']
```

Comment: this is highly inefficient, you really should use sets here, if only for not re-inventing the wheel

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga As indicated in the answer, I propose this solution in order to keep the original font (lower, upper) in case it is necessary. With sets you would lose this information :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly concise way to do this:

```
first = ['A', 'B', 'c', 'd']
second = ['a', 'b', 'e']

print(list(set(map(str.lower, first)) ^ set(map(str.lower, second))))
```

**Optionally:**

```
print(list(set(map(str.lower, first)).symmetric_difference(map(str.lower, second))))
```

**Output:**

['e', 'd', 'c']

**Note:**

Note the order of output. If order matters then sort it